# How Do I Get JeroMQ To Work With Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, zeromq, jeromq

My process:

Install IntelliJ

Create new project

Add JeroMQ with File>Project Structure>Global Libraries>org.zeromq:jeromq:0.5.1

Create the following java files in src:

publisher.java

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZContext;
import org.zeromq.SocketType;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class publisher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try (ZContext context = new ZContext()) {
            // Socket to talk to clients
            ZMQ.Socket socket = context.createSocket(SocketType.PUB);
            socket.bind("tcp://*:5559");
            System.out.println("starting loop");
            String message = "hello";
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                // Block until a message is received
                socket.send(message);

                // Print the message
                System.out.println(
                        "Sent: [" + message + "]"
                );
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

subscriber.java

```
import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZContext;
import org.zeromq.SocketType;

public class subscriber {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        try (ZContext context = new ZContext()) {
            // Socket to talk to clients
            ZMQ.Socket socket = context.createSocket(SocketType.SUB);
            socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5559");
            socket.subscribe("");
            System.out.println("starting loop");

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                // Block until a message is received
                String message = socket.recvStr(0);

                // Print the message
                System.out.println(
                        "Received: [" + message + "]"
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Run publisher.java, then subscriber.java (concurrently). Both work.

Download Android Studio (my version - 3.5.2)

Create new project (Basic Activity, API 28/Android 9.0 just for simplicity).

Modify project settings: File>Project Structure>Modules>(Compile SDK Version 29, Build Tools version 29.0.2, Source Code Compatibility 1.8, Target Compatibility 1.8)

Add JeroMQ with Build>Edit Libraries and Dependencies>Dependencies>app>org.zeromq:jeromq:0.5.1

Add the following class to app>java>(top folder):

subscriber.java

```
package com.example.testttt;

import org.zeromq.ZMQ;
import org.zeromq.ZContext;
import org.zeromq.SocketType;

public class subscriber implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try (ZContext context = new ZContext()) {
            // Socket to talk to clients
            ZMQ.Socket socket = context.createSocket(SocketType.SUB);
            socket.connect("tcp://10.0.2.2:5559");
            socket.subscribe("");
            System.out.println("starting loop");

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                // Block until a message is received
                String message = socket.recvStr(0);

                // Print the message
                System.out.println(
                        "Received: [" + message + "]"
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: uses 10.0.2.2 to connect to localhost as indicated here (https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking)).

Edit the onCreate method in the MainActivity.java file like so:

```
package com.example.testttt;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        new Thread(new subscriber()).start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Create android virtual device (Pixel 2 API 28, x86). Start it.

Click "Debug app" while publisher.java is still running on the PC. The first printed line "starting loop" appears, but no other messages appear. After a minute or so the following error appears (this isn't the full output because the body of this post is limited):

```
A/example.testtt: java_vm_ext.cc:542] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: field operation on NULL object: 0x0
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]     in call to GetIntField
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]     from void sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.preClose0(java.io.FileDescriptor)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542] "FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 Runnable
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x16400448 self=0xee1f8200
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | sysTid=4740 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xd45a0970
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | state=R schedstat=( 720319 0 12 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | stack=0xd449d000-0xd449f000 stackSize=1042KB
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #00 pc 004152f6  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+198)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #01 pc 0051048e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+382)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #02 pc 0050b743  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+83)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #03 pc 0031a8b0  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1088)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #04 pc 0031ad21  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, char*)+113)
A/example.testtt: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #05 pc 000d60f7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+71)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #06 pc 000dc5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::CheckFieldAccess(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, _jobject*, _jfieldID*, bool, art::Primitive::Type)+323)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #07 pc 000dbcc0  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::GetField(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jfieldID*, bool, art::Primitive::Type)+1056)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #08 pc 000c5c84  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::GetIntField(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jfieldID*)+68)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #09 pc 0001680d  /system/lib/libopenjdk.so (fdval+45)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #10 pc 000179f9  /system/lib/libopenjdk.so (FileDispatcherImpl_preClose0+41)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #11 pc 0011534a  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 114000) (java.lang.System.setErr0 [DEDUPED]+170)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #12 pc 005f0d52  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #13 pc 000a30df  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+239)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #14 pc 0029bca2  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+338)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #15 pc 00293e48  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1048)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #16 pc 002d75be  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE0ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+158)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #17 pc 002d1001  /system/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+73761)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #18 pc 005f7762  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+18)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #19 pc 0012b5c8  /system/framework/boot.vdex (sun.nio.ch.DatagramDispatcher.preClose)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #20 pc 002661c9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+521)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #21 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #22 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #23 pc 002d44dd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+669)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #24 pc 002d10ad  /system/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+73933)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #25 pc 005f7762  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+18)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #26 pc 0012f3b6  /system/framework/boot.vdex (sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.implCloseSelectableChannel)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #27 pc 002661c9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+521)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #28 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #29 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #30 pc 002d44dd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+669)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #31 pc 002d10ad  /system/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+73933)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #32 pc 005f7762  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+18)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #33 pc 000db5c2  /system/framework/boot.vdex (java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.implCloseChannel)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #34 pc 002661c9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+521)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #35 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #36 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #37 pc 002d44dd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+669)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #38 pc 002d10ad  /system/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+73933)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #39 pc 005f7762  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+18)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #40 pc 000db22a  /system/framework/boot.vdex (java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #41 pc 002661c9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+521)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #42 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #43 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
A/example.testtt: java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #44 pc 002d44dd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+669)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #45 pc 002d10ad  /system/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+73933)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #46 pc 005f7762  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+18)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #47 pc 0012f398  /system/framework/boot.vdex (sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finalize)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #48 pc 002661c9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+521)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #49 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #50 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #51 pc 002d44dd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE2ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+669)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #52 pc 002d10ad  /system/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+73933)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #53 pc 005f7762  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+18)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #54 pc 000aec02  /system/framework/boot-core-libart.vdex (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #55 pc 002661c9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+521)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #56 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #57 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #58 pc 002d5fce  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE1ELb0ELb0EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+286)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #59 pc 002d184a  /system/lib/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<false, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+75882)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #60 pc 005f7762  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+18)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #61 pc 000aec5c  /system/framework/boot-core-libart.vdex (java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #62 pc 002661c9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+521)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #63 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #64 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #65 pc 005bc493  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+691)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #66 pc 005e2d21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14241)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #67 pc 000aeaf8  /system/framework/boot-core-libart.vdex (java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run+20)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #68 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #69 pc 0026c79c  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+220)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #70 pc 00293e2b  /system/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1019)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #71 pc 005bd574  /system/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1444)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #72 pc 005e2f21  /system/lib/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14753)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #73 pc 000ca806  /system/framework/boot.vdex (java.lang.Thread.run+12)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #74 pc 00266216  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb.llvm.2093054539+598)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #75 pc 0026c68e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+126)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #76 pc 005a953d  /system/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1277)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #77 pc 005f6c6d  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+77)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   native: #78 pc 005f6dff  /system/lib/libart.so (???)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.preClose0(Native method)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.preClose(SocketDispatcher.java:69)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.implCloseSelectableChannel(SocketChannelImpl.java:885)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   - locked <0x07640989> (a java.lang.Object)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.implCloseChannel(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:234)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:116)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   - locked <0x0975fd8e> (a java.lang.Object)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finalize(SocketChannelImpl.java:939)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:250)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    java_vm_ext.cc:542] 
A/example.testtt: runtime.cc:558] Runtime aborting...
    runtime.cc:558] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
    runtime.cc:558] All threads:
    runtime.cc:558] DALVIK THREADS (19):
    runtime.cc:558] "FinalizerDaemon" prio=5 tid=6 Runnable
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x16400448 self=0xee1f8200
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=4740 nice=4 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xd45a0970
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=R schedstat=( 41366495 1328311 69 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=0 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0xd449d000-0xd449f000 stackSize=1042KB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #00 pc 004152f6  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+198)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #01 pc 0051048e  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+382)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #02 pc 0050b743  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+83)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #03 pc 0052e564  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+916)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #04 pc 00526286  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+534)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #05 pc 005254d4  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+1316)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #06 pc 004efdcc  /system/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpAllThreads(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, art::Thread*) const+284)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #07 pc 004dc52f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+287)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #08 pc 005cd833  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNSt3__110__function6__funcIPFvPKcENS_9allocatorIS5_EES4_EclEOS3_+35)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #09 pc 00007ccc  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+828)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #10 pc 0031ab5f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1775)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #11 pc 0031ad21  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortV(char const*, char const*, char*)+113)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #12 pc 000d60f7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::AbortF(char const*, ...)+71)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #13 pc 000dc5b3  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::ScopedCheck::CheckFieldAccess(art::ScopedObjectAccess&, _jobject*, _jfieldID*, bool, art::Primitive::Type)+323)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #14 pc 000dbcc0  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::GetField(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jfieldID*, bool, art::Primitive::Type)+1056)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #15 pc 000c5c84  /system/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::CheckJNI::GetIntField(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jfieldID*)+68)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #16 pc 0001680d  /system/lib/libopenjdk.so (fdval+45)
    runtime.cc:558]   native: #17 pc 000179f9  /system/lib/libopenjdk.so (FileDispatcherImpl_preClose0+41)
    runtime.cc:558]   at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.preClose0(Native method)
    runtime.cc:558]   at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.preClose(SocketDispatcher.java:69)
    runtime.cc:558]   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.implCloseSelectableChannel(SocketChannelImpl.java:885)
    runtime.cc:558]   - locked <0x07640989> (a java.lang.Object)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.implCloseChannel(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:234)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.close(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:116)
    runtime.cc:558]   - locked <0x0975fd8e> (a java.lang.Object)
A/example.testtt: runtime.cc:558]   at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finalize(SocketChannelImpl.java:939)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:250)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:237)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:103)
    runtime.cc:558]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    runtime.cc:558] 
    runtime.cc:558] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
    runtime.cc:558]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x756c6ee0 self=0xee1f4000
    runtime.cc:558]   | sysTid=4694 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf2dbb494
    runtime.cc:558]   | state=S schedstat=( 916061562 62246943 365 ) utm=72 stm=19 core=3 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:558]   | stack=0xff6bc000-0xff6be000 stackSize=8MB
    runtime.cc:558]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: ep_poll+0x28e/0x33f
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_epoll_wait+0x96/0xb4
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: SyS_epoll_pwait+0x93/0x114
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: do_fast_syscall_32+0xd5/0x148
    runtime.cc:558]   kernel: sysenter_flags_fixed+0x8/0x12
```

Any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you declare in your app's manifest the permission to access the internet?

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't remember--and I'm teleworking so it'll be some time before I can check my work computer. My eventual solution was "don't use Android Studio," but I'm not sure that qualifies as an SO answer.